# Is it neccessary to have "control unit next state register" to be FALLING edge triggered ?

Tags: processor, digital, microprocessors, digital-logic

[image: cpu]

Each module can be consider to have following power:
[1] It can store data.
[2] It can operate on the data.(arithmetic operation)

some property of modules (listing just that, i am concerned with right now.)
[1] all register/memory element in modules are RAISING edge triggered.

Now this architecture can be use to create a model of a computer processor.

Real Deal:
Is it neccessary to have "control unit next state register" to be FALLING egde triggered ? 
(below i explain why i think so)

```
CLOCK: 
     |------|         |------|[1]      |------|         |------|    
_____|      |_________|      |_________|      |_________|      |____     
                   |----| 
                 Data should be valid in this region at least.(considering the setup/hold time).
            |----------------|[1]
____________|                |_________
So the write signal should be up (if control unit want to) in this region.
```

This control signals are just the conbinational result of input and CURRENT STATE.
SO that means as the current state changes the control signal changes, which implies the state should change at falling edge[1].
So  change of state is simply the change in "control unit state register" which is happening at the falling edge of the clock.
Thats why i think "Is it necessary to have "control unit next state register" to be FALLING edge triggered" ....am i thinking/considering things right ?

If yes then the same(falling edge triggered of control unit state register ) should be happening in actual processor as well.

I am learning stuff so please forgive + correct my mistakes

Answer (score 0):

A common way to handle this is to consider the rising edge of the clock to trigger the “fetch” cycle, and the falling edge to trigger the “execute” cycle.

During “fetch” the memory address is incremented and data from memory is alowed to stabilize and propagate to control circuits (such as ALU’s settings , demultiplexers to control things,  multiplexers to sample states for conditional tests, set up shift logic, etc).

During “execute” the things being controlled by the control circuit outputs are triggered (i.e. the test state being read by a multiplexer would be tested, and if true a branch might be taken by loading the program counter with the branch address,so that during the next fetch cycle the system would load the next instruction from the branch address instead of simply incrementing to the next address in memory ).

ANSWERED by: a generous man "BL" (name initials)

Comment: Logically make sense . 
But how one would implement it...This require to have separate "control unit next state register" for fetch state and multiplexer to select between state register.
This will only save us half the clock cycle in fetch cycle only, right